# image not showing in IE transparent url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat top left any reason

Tags: html

We have 1 image which is getting set through css
 transparent url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat top left
this image is coming when accessed through firefox but not when accessed through Internet Explorer.
Any thoughts/suggestions ?

Comment: Add your code please to https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

IE only supports content property with "after" and "before" selectors.  Instead of using img element, you may use div or sth else with before or after selector to set the content as image. Or simply do it with JS

Please try the fallowing code

```
  <style>

    .custom-image:before {
    content: url("myimg.jpg");
    padding-top:5px;
    width:60px;
    }

  </style>

<a class=custom-image></a>
```